# Iterating through a tuple array without using a loop

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

I have an array that i would like to iterate over without using a loop (no loops is part of the requirements) and I'm really stuck on how I'm meant to do this without a loop?

basically i have the following code:

```
i = state_col[0]
j = state_col[1]

for neighbour in surface_neigbhours(i):
    neighbours = state[neighbour]
    if abs(j - neighbours) > 1:
        return True
    return False
```

The functions surface neighbours returns a tuple of tuples as such: ((1,1), (2,1), (3,1)) this are coordinates that are then placed into another variable 'state' to create a new variable.

For example we have state as ((0,0,0)(0,0,0)(0,0,0))
then i want to extract those three values at the neighbours coordinates and check if they have a difference greater than 1.

Is there anyway to do this without a for loop?

Comment: Your loop is strange, because you can NEVER iterate on more than the first item as there is a `return` in it

Comment: Short answer: no. If you want to iterate, the traditional way is with a loop. Whether you write it yourself or use one embedded in some other code the loop is still there. (I also count recursion as a form of looping).

Comment: Thats because, if the requirment is met even once then i don't care about the rest, as soon as a true is spotted it should break out and return true.

Comment: I'm considering using recursion because thats not technical a 'loop' but this function is actually already a recursion of another loop. is having a recursion function within another recursion function weird?

Comment: But, just note, that `as soon as a true` is *not* spotted, you break out and return `False`. Also if you post code which has a `return`, then you should show how it is part of a function, otherwise all the other python programmers will believe you have a syntax error.